# Library function to do bean comparison using Functions?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

Since Java 8 has made it easier than ever to refer to method directly (Function/lambda), the traditional reflection-based bean comparators (E.g. common-lang's `EqualsBuilder`) can now be implemented cleanly without reflection. I am wondering is this available in any well-known library already?

Just to be clear, I am after a function similar to this signature:

```
static <T> boolean equals(T a, T b, Function<T, ?>... propRefs);
```

Alternatively, the most non-confusion way of implementing this using Streams?

Comment: Something like `return !Arrays.stream(propRefs).anyMatch(f -> !Objects.equals(f.apply(a), f.apply(b)));` would probably work.

Comment: Yeah, that is exactly what I needed. In addition, using `allMatch` can avoid the double negation and `Stream` has an `of` method which takes an array directly. However, considering efficiency and safety, it would be better to take an immutable List instead of computing the var-arg array again and again.

Comment: yes good idea to use allMatch - `Stream.of(array)` calls `Arrays.stream(array)` so they are equivalent in this case but the former is a bit shorter indeed.

Comment: @billc.cn: do you really think about the performance issue of a varargs array when comparing with `EqualsBuilder`? Did you ever think about how many unnecessary operation that solution performs?

Comment: @Holger I have not benched this, but using the revision on my last comment (external immutable list), such equals method should be way more efficient than the reflection-based `EqualsBuilder`. This is assuming lambda invocation is close to native efficiency (due to invokedynamic, etc.) and reflection is super slow.

Comment: @billc.cn: maybe my statement wasn’t clear, so you got it wrong. I wanted to say that `EqualsBuilder`, even the non-Reflection based, looks so inefficient that you don’t need to worry about potential issues with a single array created for varargs. But for completeness, my solution contains a variant that works without any temporary object…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given an example class like

```
class Person {
    long id;
    String name, surname;
    int age;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
}
```

Of course, we can do it in the most compact form like

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if(obj==this) return true;
    if(!(obj instanceof Person)) return false;
    Person p=(Person)obj;
    return Stream.<Function<Person,?>>of(
          Person::getName, Person::getSurname, Person::getAge)
      .allMatch(f->Objects.equals(f.apply(this), f.apply(p)));
}
```

but it raises the big question whether it really is a win compared to the simple form

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if(obj==this) return true;
    if(!(obj instanceof Person)) return false;
    Person p=(Person)obj;
    return this.age==p.age && Objects.equals(this.name, p.name)
      && Objects.equals(this.surname, p.surname);
}
```

as it doesn’t add to brevity of the code and can’t prevent neither, forgetting a significant property nor mismatches between this `equals` implementation and the `hashCode` implementation.

Note that this also applies to the `EqualsBuilder`; it’s not really helping regarding the most critical issues (actually, I can’t see *any* advantage).

If we want to gain an advantage out of it, we have to resort to a not-so compact implementation:

```
static List<Function<Person,?>> EQ_PROPS=Arrays.asList(
    Person::getName, Person::getSurname, Person::getAge);

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if(obj==this) return true;
    if(!(obj instanceof Person)) return false;
    Person p=(Person)obj;
    return EQ_PROPS.stream().allMatch(f->Objects.equals(f.apply(this), f.apply(p)));
}
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(EQ_PROPS.stream().map(f->f.apply(this)).toArray());
}
```

we still can’t guaranty that there is no relevant property missing, but at least we have a single point of responsibility that we need to check and we have ensured that the equality and hash code are consistent, so there is finally *one* advantage over manual implementation.

If you worry about the performance implication of temporary objects, you may combine all functions to the actual operation which can be performed without any temporary object:

```
static List<Function<Person,?>> EQ_PROPS=Arrays.asList(
    Person::getName, Person::getSurname, Person::getAge);

static BiPredicate<Person,Person> EQUAL=EQ_PROPS.stream()
    .<BiPredicate<Person,Person>>map(f -> (a,b) -> Objects.equals(f.apply(a), f.apply(b)))
    .reduce(BiPredicate::and).get();

static ToIntFunction<Person> HASH=EQ_PROPS.stream()
    .<ToIntFunction<Person>>map(f -> a -> Objects.hash(f.apply(a)))
    .reduce((f,g) -> x -> f.applyAsInt(x)*31+g.applyAsInt(x)).get();

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return obj==this || (obj instanceof Person)&& EQUAL.test(this, (Person)obj);
}
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return HASH.applyAsInt(this);
}
```